# Loop through several ListViews (in a TabControl) and clearing checkboxes c#

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox, tabcontrol, listviewitem

This is driving me nuts!
I have a TabControl wich holds 5 tabs. Each tab has a ListView with multiple checkboxes.
Now i'd like to pass my TabControl to a method and for each ListView - clear all checkboxes.

Doesn't seem so hard, but it was!

```
foreach (var myItem in tabControl1.Controls) {
    if (myItem is ListView) { // surprisingly doesnt work...
        // loop through ListView find CheckBox...
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the if-statement?

Edit: This code works! Hmm?!

```
foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView1.Items)
{
    listItem.Checked = false;
}
```

Solution: I Was looking for "CheckBox", but it's actually a ListViewItem with the property Checked = true/false.

Also see code below, nice recursive method!

Comment: What's inside the loop (inside the `if`)?

Comment: Nothing so far, just a Console.WriteLine("trololo"); Wich doesnt run. Seems that myItem is a TabPage. Hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursively:

```
void ClearAllCheckBoxes(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in ctrl.Controls)
        if (childControl is ListView)
            foreach (ListViewItem item in ((ListView)childControl).Items)
                item.Checked = false;
        else ClearAllCheckBoxes(childControl);
}
```

And use:

```
ClearAllCheckBoxes(tabControl1);
```

Comment: Wow, nice cast :) OK testing that.. :)

Comment: Crashed, says listView is null. Maybe I should place it outside the loop?

Comment: @Half_Baked Updated again.

Comment: System.InvalidCastException

Comment: @Half_Baked Do you have things besides the ListView there?

Comment: Oh.. I forgot, sorry. Yes a few labels, and it's wrapped inside a panel also. Maybe this is not possible?

Comment: @Half_Baked How about now?

Comment: It doesn't crash, but they are not unchecked

Comment: The thing is - When you get the `Control`s - you only get the immediate controls - not the nested ones. A recursive approach (- a method that calls itself..) can handle that. But let's try simpler. Does the panel contain the checkboxes or the listview?

Comment: The listview has the "Checkboxes" set to True. So i'm not sure how that works, if it creates a checkboxItem? Maybe its just better to skip passing the whole tab. Instead just add ListView1 instead?

Comment: I added a (tested) answer assuming the listView is inside the Panel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42339/discussion-between-half-baked-and-ispiro)

Comment: Ok I'm testing. But since it's only 5 tabs, i could just manually run the loop inside the listview 5 times instead....

Comment: Since I am actually testing each one (Since the second or third) - your `Controls` must be a little differently arranged than what I'm testing. I therefore wrote a recursive method. (See edit) If this doesn't work - I'm not sure what's wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Trying your recursive method :)

Comment: Ahh, I got it! It's not Checkbox!! It's a property of ListViewItem! ListViewItem.Checked = true/false !!!

Comment: @Half_Baked Glad I could be of help.